# Present Perfect and Past Simple together

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, perfect-aspect, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I just wonder if i have a possibility to mix these tenses in this way. For example, i say about things happened in the past. Can i use present perfect to show result of this sentences in present? I know that i can do that with Present Simple but Past Simple suits it for me too. I can give you an example

- I've gain weight after i ate many pizzas

or

- The day was bad for me anyway.I went to school and in the hall I broke my leg.Because of that I've gained a scar.

Comment: *Because of that I've **gained** a scar*. Present Perfect is auxiliary ***have*** + PAST PARTICIPLE ***gained***, not "unmarked infinitive" ***gain***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers oops yes, my mistake. But is using these tenses in that way right?